# "Cannot Verify Server Identity" alert on iOS device - how to find source?

Tags: ios

I'm getting an odd error suddenly and presumably due to an old certificate that I probably accepted many years ago when I used to use Adium on macOS via iMessage / Messages.  Suddenly, just today, I started getting the following popup in all sorts of apps on iOS 13 on my iPad and iOS 13 on my iPhone:

[image: error]

> Cannot Verify Server Identity
>
> The identity of "trac.adium.im" cannot be verified.
>
> Review the certificate details to continue.
>
> Continue | Details | Cancel

Since I can’t determine if this message come from the front most app or system settings I’ll need some help with how I can locate what setting or app is calling a site that no longer has a signed certificate that iOS trusts.

What steps can triage this?

Comment: The errors might be due to someone hacking your router or DNS service, and intercepting your network connections. Since this is a risk, be very careful about what you do on your network until you figure out what's going on. What does the "Details" button show about the problem?

Comment: `Details` reveals nothing and my firewall is not compromised.

Comment: did you fix this issue? It seems pretty old but thought to ask. Have you check your Mailbox setting too if there is anything from this domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Apple fixed this issue within a few months after I had reported the issue a couple of times and pestered them. The problem came back once, but then finally went away after another update.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the settings app, delete all profiles you don’t know you need and maybe the rest.

Also, VPN profiles could be implicated and for an edge case, look to any iCloud keychains on macOS.

I would make a back up as well in case you end up erasing the contents and settings and restoring from backup after being sure it’s not coming from your network with a clean iOS device that joins your network.

Comment: None of these revealed the problem.  My keychains do not sync to iCloud, but even so I removed entries for the specific `trac.adium.im` on my macOS Keychain.app certificate entries.

Comment: @ylluminate What’s even creepier is if that site had a valid cert, your phone wouldn’t even tell you it’s talking to it based on your description.

Answer (score 1):

I suddenly began seeing this same pop-up alert all over my iOS device.

Had no idea what was causing it and was afraid my network had somehow been hacked.

It ended up being a [shared iCal Calendar](http://icalshare.com/) that I had joined. The sport event that I had join the calendar for ended, and the calendar creator must have then made some kind of change to their site.

Check any **shared iCloud Calendar** that you have joined. I deleted the calendar and have not seen the alert since.

[image: Cannot Verify Server Identity]

> Cannot Verify Server Identity
>
> The identity of "123kid.in" cannot be verified. Review the certificate details to continue.
>
> Continue | Details | Cancel

Comment: the certificate enabling https on the "123kid.in" server most likely expired.